# Convergence of Laurent series principal part

Tags: convergence-divergence

Suppose $f(z)$ has Laurent series expansion in a neighborhood of $z=p$:
$$f(z)=\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}a_k(z-p)^k$$

A series I am interested in is
$$S(z):=\sum^{-1}_{k=-\infty}a_{2k}\frac{(z-p)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

Is it true that, for a fixed real $\theta$,
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+}S(p+re^{i\theta})=\infty$$
?

---

By series multisection, if $p=0$, $S(z)$ is equal to the principal part of the Laurent series of
$$\int\frac{f(z)+f(-z)}2dz$$
However, in most cases $p\ne 0$, and I am not sure how does this help to prove the limit.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: take
$$f(z) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{-1}\frac{z^{-2k+1}}{(-2k + 1)!},$$
convergent for every $z\ne 0$ and $S(z) = 0$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$.

In fact, when a finite number of $a_{2k}\ne 0$, $S$ has a pole and your condition is true. With a infinite number of $a_{2k}\ne 0$, $S$ has an essential singularity and the limit does not exists.

Comment: Can you find a counter example with not all coefficient of $z^{-2n}$ equal to zero? My intuition says no, but there may be exceptions.

Comment: @Szeto, with a finite number of $a_{2k}\ne 0$, $S$ has a pole and your condition is true. With a infinite number of $a_{2k}\ne 0$, $S$ has a essential singularity and the limit $\not\exists$.

Comment: Thank you. Please add that to your answer, and then I will accept it.